# Why doesn't the data from the server come to the app on the real device?

Tags: android, server

When the application starts, a request is sent to the server (which is located locally on my computer) to get a list of posts. In theory, the server should process the request and return this list of posts. But it doesn't return anything. In LogCat there are no errors, but when debugging, an exception is thrown instead of a server response:

```
((SocketTimeoutException)e).detailMessage = failed to connect to /192.168.1.35 (port 9999) from /192.168.1.33 (port 49742) after 30000ms
```

When I try to add new post (post to server via Post method) I get error at LogCat. Here is the text of the error:

```
2021-11-02 21:17:29.025 12197-12210/com.example E/SpellCheckerSession: ignoring processOrEnqueueTask due to unexpected mState=TASK_CLOSE scp.mWhat=TASK_CLOSE
2021-11-02 21:17:39.811 12197-12568/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.example, PID: 12197
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.35 (port 9999) from /192.168.1.33 (port 49918) after 30000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.kt:63)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
        at com.example.repository.PostRepositoryImpl.save(PostRepositoryImpl.kt:60)
        at com.example.viewmodel.PostViewModel$save$1$1.invoke(PostViewModel.kt:54)
        at com.example.viewmodel.PostViewModel$save$1$1.invoke(PostViewModel.kt:53)
        at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
```

IP-address and port are correct. On native android-studio emulator I enter address 10.0.2.2:9999 - posts are coming. I use Genymotion emulator (which has its own IP) and enter 192.168.1.35:9999 - the answer from the server comes too. Only the real devices (Xiaomi Redmi 5 and Nexus 5X) do not respond. Help to solve the problem, please!

UPD: Thanks everybody for your help, guys! I've tried everything, but the problem was really caused by the turned on firewall)

Comment: Aside from ensuring that port 9999 is open on your server machine, see if you can ping your mobile phone from it.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345051/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be ;-)

Comment: http:// or https:// ? Android version of used device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall on the server pc can block incoming connections. Switch it off to test.

The server can be bound to localhost only. Dont bind your server and if you have to bind it to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: You probably don't want to turn off the firewall completely.  Poke a hole in it for connections from inside the network to that device/port.

Answer (score 0):

The key line here is this one:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.35 (port 9999) from /192.168.1.33 (port 49918) after 30000ms
```

It tells us it "failed to connect", it tells us it was as a "SocketTimeoutException" and that no response was recieved after 30s.

This is just the TCP connection request and so it likely a networking issue somewhere between the client and the serer.

As it is not a no route found error the first thing to check would be any firewalls.